# Href link issues

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to display all the projects I have coded in my career for my portfolio. I made them into an obj called projects and have mapped through them to render. The problem is that a lot of them are not deployed yet so, for those I want an alert saying "not linked yet" but the link is defaulted to local:3000 and just reloads the page

```
portfolio: [
{
  name: "OmniFood",
  description: "",
  imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/hvLOGi1KsF02XiZ1DD/giphy.gif",
  href: "https://github.io/SbOmniFood/"
},
{
  name: "Forkify",
  description: "",
  imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/ekeOYzzNEpW73RIcSb/giphy.gif",
  href: ""
},
{
  name: "Connect Four",
  description: "",
  imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/YrC2lEAcG4loOj2aLI/giphy.gif",
  href: ""
},
```

here is how i render it.

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <h1>Check Out Some of My Projects!</h1>
    <div className="portfolioGrid">
      {resumeData.portfolio &&
        resumeData.portfolio.map(item => {
          return (
            <a href={`${item.href}`} target="_blank">
              <div className="portfolio-item portfolioGridSquare">
                <div className="item-wrap">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${item.imgurl}`}
                      alt="my projects"
                      className="item-img"
                    />

                    <div className="overlay">
                      <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                        <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          );
        })}
      <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className=""></div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: so do not render the `a` tag if you have not `item.href`. in the return the map put an if before and if `item.href` return the `a` tag with all in there. ELSE return `div` tag with all in there and make an event onClick that call an alert

Answer (score 0):

You should only render a link if the project has a valid href. For example:

```js
const PortfolioList = () => (
  <div className="portfolioGrid">
    {portfolio.map(item => item.href ? (
      <a href={item.href} target="_blank">
        <PortfolioItem item={item} />
      </a>
    ) : (
      <div onClick={() => alert("not linked yet")}>
        <PortfolioItem item={item} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const PortfolioItem = ({ item }) => (
  <div className="portfolio-item portfolioGridSquare">
    <div className="item-wrap">
      <div>
        <img src={`${item.imgurl}`} alt="my projects" className="item-img" />

        <div className="overlay">
          <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
            <h5>{item.name}</h5>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```